# Calculate surface integral given $G = x^2\,\mathbf i + xy\,\mathbf j + z\,\mathbf k$

Tags: calculus

Let $G = x^2\,\mathbf i + xy\,\mathbf j + z\,\mathbf k$ and let $S$ be the flat triangular surface with vertices $(0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 1, 0)$, $(2, 2, 2)$. Assume $S$ is oriented towards the postive $x$-axis.

Find $ \iint_S G\mathrm dS.$

This appeared on my calc II practice exam. I was told that it’s calleed a surface integral. I parametrised the surface and found 0=2x-2y. I’m not sure if this is correct. And I’m also uncertain about how to proceed.

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE! Can you share the attempts you made with us? If you show your attempts, the community will be more willing to help you. Also, it might be helpful to provide some context to the question (What is your background knowledge? Where did you find the question? etc.)

Comment: This appeared on my calc II practice exam. I was told that it’s calleed a surface integral. I parametrised the surface and found 0=2x-2y. I’m not sure if this is correct. And I’m also uncertain about how to proceed.