# Surface integral with flat triangle surface

Tags: calculus

Let $G=2x\hat{i}+xy\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$ and let S be the flat triangular surface with vertices $(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(2,2,2)$. Assume $S$ is oriented towards the positive $x$-axis.

Find $\iint GdS,$ (over S).

This appeared on my Calculus III practice exam. I was told that it’s called a surface integral. I parametrised the surface and found $0=2x-2y$. I’m not sure if this is correct. And I’m also uncertain about how to proceed.

Comment: isn't it meant to be d$\mathbf S$ not dS ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate surface integral given $G = x^2\,\mathbf i + xy\,\mathbf j + z\,\mathbf k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955111/calculate-surface-integral-given-g-x2-mathbf-i-xy-mathbf-j-z-mathb)

Comment: Dear Tom123456123456, I've noticed that you already asked this question one day ago. Please don't re-ask the same question over and over again. It is possible that you won't get an answer immediately. Make sure your question is clear. E.g. I see that you wrote the point $(0,0,0)$ twice, and that the vector field is not the same as in your previous answer (the $i$-component is $2x$ instead of $x^2$ now).